# Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified - Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, text

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'']]
[dir:  E:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\PyCharm Projects]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;E:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.5;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\]
[Finished]
```

I get this when I try to build any code with Sublime Text 2.
I added my Python 3.5 to the path, and it still comes up with this error message. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `Python` is still not part of your environment variable `PATH`.

Go to `My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables` and verify "C:\python35;" is at the beginning of `PATH`. If so, relaunch `Sublime`.

In Sublime, open the console with "(ctrl-`)" run `os.getenv("PATH")` and see if `C:\python35;` is in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running python on Anaconda, the process is the same. For example in windows:
you need a 'variable' PATH
with the 'value' C:\Users\Anaconda3

notice that in my case anaconda was installed in Users